# delete uploaded file from folder using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am sending a HTTP request to upload a file. And the request is setup like this:

[uploadFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCbrC.png)

And, the Directory Listing plugin pointing to a directory with all files and the request picks one file at a time. It works fine when run with one thread but, when i run in multiple threads, i see that already uploaded file is picked again to upload which leads to error.

I have added regular expression extrator to get the filename from the request body like this:

[extract-filename-from-requestbody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/theAP.png)

And then, I am trying to use a post processor beanshell script to either delete the file from the folder or move to a different folder. But, not been successful. Need some help on this.

The first issue is i am not sure if i am extracting the value the right way. The value is to be got from request body and not request header. But, i dont see that option in the extractor.

Second, i am unable to use/retrieve the value from the extractor. Tried vars.get, vars.getObject and simply "${fileName}". Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that deleting the file will help because Directory Listing Config reads the folder at the beginning of the test (see [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) chapter) so no matter whether the file is physically present or not JMeter will try to upload it

If you want to get unique files without repetitions just **untick** "Rewind on end of list" box:

[image]

This way each virtual user will read the next value so there will be no duplicates. When the last file will be used - the test will stop.

More information: [Introducing the Directory Listing Config Plugin on JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter)

Also going forward [consider using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language instead of Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), it's the recommended option since JMeter 3.1

Comment: I have the "Rewind on end of list" unchecked. The issue i am facing is that 2 threads pick the same file to upload.

Comment: I had "Independent list per thread" checked. I just unchecked this option and now it seems to work fine.